# how to reduce the integral to a Gamma function

Tags: calculus, integration, gamma-function

The equation is 
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp(4t − \exp(t))\ dt
$$
I am not sure what variable should I change here? Does $u=\exp(t)-4t$ work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** $e^t=u$ then
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp(4t − \exp(t))\ dt
=
\int_{0}^\infty u^3e^{-u} dt
=\Gamma(4)
=6
$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Just substitute $u = e^t $ and we get $$I = \int_{0}^{\infty} u^3e^{-u} \mathrm {d}u = \Gamma (3+1) = \Gamma (4) =6$$ Hope it helps.